# I want to delete values from an interval of keys from a list of key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a function to delete some values from an interval given by two keys from a list of key value pairs in **Python**.

I've tried a lot of things, I already googled it a lot. This is the list of key value pair:

```
[{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": in}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": in}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": out}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": in}]
```

I want to delete the values that have `"day"` value between `1 and 3`. Here's my UI code for this function. I just need to make the **`delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd)`** working.

```
all_transactions = [{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": in}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": in}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": out}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": in}]

def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions,dayStart,dayEnd):
  for i in range(0,len(all_transactions)):
    if all_transactions[i]["day"]==dayStart:
      for j in range(i+1, len(all_transactions)):
        if all_transactions[j]["day"]==dayEnd:
          del all_transactions[i:j]  
    
def ui_delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions):
  dayStart=int(input("Start day= "))
  dayEnd=int(input("End day= "))
  delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd)

ui_delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions)
print(all_transactions)
```

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: The expected output will be the list without the values that have the key value between those 2 dates (in my example 1 and 3).

Comment: list has items, list has no values, it's only dictionary has keys:values pairs (and that's pairs are to be called items too)

Comment: What you've shown is not valid Python due to a value being a keyword **in**. Please show an example of actual data. When you say "between" 1 and 3 do you mean 2? Or 1->3 inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this solve you problem :

```py
# Set up a function 

def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions, dayStart, dayEnd):
    i=0
    while i<=len(all_transactions)-1:
        if all_transactions[i]["day"]>=dayStart and all_transactions[i]["day"]<=dayEnd:
            del all_transactions[i]
        else:
            i+=1
    return all_transactions

# Let's try the folowing list

lst=[{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": 'out'}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": 'in'}]

# Apply the above function

lst=delete_transaction_interval(lst, 1, 3)

lst
```

**Output :**

```py
[{"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": 'in'}]
```

Comment: `all_transactions` is type <list> => you can't do this `del all_transactions[i]` with list

Comment: It worked well on my side. Please check "5.2. The del statement" in the following docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I didn't know it, that's cool

Answer (score 3):

You should not try to modify a list or any other mutable object while enumerating it. Best practice is to create a new object - a list in this case.

Input data adjusted to make it valid Python.

```
_in = 0
_out = 0

_list = [{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": _in}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": _in}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": _out}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": _in}]

new_list = [d for d in _list if not 1 <= d.get('day', 2) <= 3]

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'day': 4, 'sum': 99, 'type': 0}]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: <=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: @SebastianFilipovici That's because your data are not as shown in your question. Your input list contains a dictionary that does not have a 'day' key. I'll edit the code to allow for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution. We create a list comprehension that only selects key/value pairs which satisfy the condition 1 <= "day" <=3:

```
d1 = [{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": "in"}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": "in"}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": "out"}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": "in"}]          
d2 = [i for i in d1 if not 1 <= i.get("day") <=3] 
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
[{'day': 4, 'sum': 99, 'type': 'in'}]
```

Comment: OP wants to remove day values between 1 and 3

Comment: Exception has occurred: KeyError
'day'

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
l = [{"day": 1, "sum": 25, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 2, "sum": 55, "type": 'in'}, {"day": 3, "sum": 154, "type": 'out'}, {"day": 4, "sum": 99, "type": 'in'}]

def delete_transaction_interval(all_transactions,dayStart,dayEnd):
    return [d for e,d in enumerate(all_transactions) if not d.get('day') in range(dayStart,dayEnd+1)]

print(delete_transaction_interval(l,1,3))   #[{'day': 4, 'sum': 99, 'type': 'in'}]
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: KeyError 'day'

Comment: I've edited my answer. And this exception means that there is some 'transaction' that doesn't has 'day' key.